# How to paginate a result array in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I have a `find()` method in my `if else statement` that queries the database and returns the data as an array. The `if` part works fine. The problem is in the `else` part. When I try to access the index interface in the browser, am getting this error.

```
Unable to locate an object compatible with paginate. 

RuntimeException
```

From what I have gathered so far, the `paginate() method` works with objects not arrays. Am stuck on how to come to my desired outcome. Am new to CakePHP, a not so advanced/complicated response would be appreciated. Thanks

```
/**
* Assets Controller
*
*
* @method \App\Model\Entity\Asset[] paginate($object = null, array $settings = [])
*/

class AssetsController extends AppController
 {
/**
 * Index method
 *
 * @return \Cake\Http\Response|void
 */
public function index()
{
    $this->loadModel('Users');
    $username = $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.username');
    $userdetail = $this->Users->find('all')->where(['username' => $username])->first();
    $school = $userdetail->school_unit;
    $roleid = $userdetail->role_id;

    if ($roleid == 1) {
        $this->paginate = [
            'contain' => ['SchoolUnits', 'AssetConditions', 'AssetCategories', 'AssetGroups', 'AssetStatus']
        ];

        $assets = $this->paginate($this->Assets);

        $this->set(compact('assets'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['assets']);
    } else {

        $results = $this->Assets->find('all')->contain(['SchoolUnits', 'AssetConditions', 'AssetCategories', 'AssetGroups', 'AssetStatus'])->where(['school_unit_id' => $school])->first();
        $assets = $this->paginate($this->$results);

        $this->set(compact('assets'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['assets']);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're calling `->first()` which returns just a single record. Why would you try to paginate one record?

Comment: Also `$this->$results` is not going to be remotely useful here.

Comment: @GregSchmidt right, those two changes have resolved the issue. Thanks